# How to change time and compare it in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ssh

I am using a script to compare time but getting the error, `Quarterly_File.sh: line 139: [[: 0148: value too great for base (error token is "0142").` Is there any way I could change my inputs in time (hour) format and compare it with other time? My inputs are as follows.

```
startTime=00:45
endTime=01:30
fileTime=01:42
```

I am simply comparing them by removing `:` between them, like below.

```
if (0142 -ge 0045 && 0142 -lt 0130)
    then 
    // my logic
fi
```

Note that time range could be anything within a one-hour range.

**Examples**

```
0000    0045,
0030    0130,
2345    0014 (of next day)
```

Comment: You are not comparing time, from the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic) "Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers".

Comment: Anyway, you have to convert the dates to seconds and then perform the ops.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you're going to use `(` and `)` with bash operators <strike>however this would work:</strike>

```
if [ 0142 -ge 0045 ] && [ 0142 -lt 0130 ]; then
    echo "yep"
fi
```

If that's not what you're looking for, please paste as much relevant code as possible.

#### edit:

*As pointed out in the comments below, this would indeed cause issues as it's comparing octal numbers to (eventually after 10am) decimal numbers*

I would recommend using `date` to convert time to seconds, then compare that.

An example would be:

```
# grab these however you are currently
time1="01:42"
time2="00:45"
time3="01:42"
time4="01:30"

time1Second=$(date -d "${time1}" +%s)
time2Second=$(date -d "${time2}" +%s)
time3Second=$(date -d "${time3}" +%s)
time4Second=$(date -d "${time4}" +%s)

# then your comparison operators and logic:
if [ "$time1Second" -ge "$time2Second" ] && [ "$time3Second" -lt "$time4second" ]; then
    # logic here
    echo true
fi
```

This way, you are always comparing numbers in the same base

Comment: spot on, cheers. forgot how bash handles octal. Edited

Answer (score 0):

Convert the times to minutes and compare those

```
startTime=00:45
fileTime=01:42

hr=${startTime/:*} mn=${startTime/*:}      # Split hh:mm into hours and minutes
startMins=$(( ${hr#0} * 60 + ${mn#0} ))    # Minutes since midnight

hr=${fileTime/:*} mn=${fileTime/*:}
fileMins=$(( ${hr#0} * 60 + ${mn#0} ))

if [[ $fileMins -ge $startMins ]]; then : ...; fi
```